# MEF - imported object is null in the constructor

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, unity-container, mef

I'm using MEF in order to inject UnityContainer into the plugins in my application.

each one of the Plugins hold panels.

I want to transfer the Unity container into the panels also by MEF.

I need to use the Unity in the constructor of the panels.

The problem is that the Unity is not getting initialized.

So, I use the CompositionContainer.ComposeParts(panel) in the Plugin after I created the panel. The 
problem is that I want to use the Unity in the constructor of the panels.

I don't want to send the the UnityContainer or the CompositionContainer as a parameter in the panel's constructor.

thanks

Comment: You should post some code how you are initializing MEF (creating catalogs) and how you are using the Imports/Exports attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you dont have posted some code so i just assume:

if you do it that way:

```
public class Bar
{
   [ImportingConstructor]
   public Bar(IMyImportedService service)
   {
      //service should not be null
   }
}
```

if you do it this way

```
public class Bar
{
   [Import]
   private IMyImportedService service;

   public Bar()
   {
      //service should be null, because you have to implement IPartImportsSatisfiedNotificationand use OnImportsSatisfied
   }
}
```